# How can I find the API a website uses, when the website is server-side rendered?

Tags: html, api, server-side-rendering, client-side

I have found that it is easy to find the API when a website uses client-side rendering. Unfortunately, the website I am looking at uses server-side rendering and I am trying to find the API. Articles that talk about how to find the API always only explain how to do it for client-side rendered websites and then dismiss server-side, "because it is a lot more complicated".
My question is if it is even possible to find the API from a server-side rendered website and if anybody would have any starting point for me since I am unable to find anything.

Comment: The server is a black box to you. If all you get is what the server returns, and there’s no hint for any APIs in that, then that’s that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

You don't have access to the server-side code so you have no way of telling where it is getting the data from.

Maybe it is a public web service. Maybe it is a private web service. Maybe it is direct access to a database. Maybe it is reading data from static files on the server's local file system. You have no way of telling.